# Filtering an array of objects based on a condition

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array in the following format :-

```
[
 { name : "Foo",
   type : "Bar"
 },
 { 
  name : "Foo",
  type : "Row"
 },
 { 
  name : "Foo"
 }
]
```

I would like to remove occurrences of "Foo" only when it doesn't have a type. Basically, there can be duplicates in the array as long as the type is different and there can not be a duplicate with no type. Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include **attempted solutions**, **why they didn't work**, and the expected results.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that you are working with a json_decoded array of objects.  IN that case, you could run a simple `array_filter()` like this:

```
$filtered_array = array_filter($array, function($item) {
   return isset($item->type);
});
```

Comment: Hey Mike, thanks for the reply! I do not want to remove all items if there isn't a type set. I only want to remove items where a type isn't set only when there are duplicates of it with a type set. I hope you understand what I am saying?

Comment: @MadhanPadmanabhan OK I guess I misinterpreted that statement that `I would like to remove occurrences of "Foo" only when it doesn't have a type`. In that case, you probably need to walk through the array more manually and possibly store metadata from it temporarily into a separate data structure, which can then be utilized to determine which elements in the original array need to be filtered.  I am not going to work up a solution here, as I wold like to see you make an attempt first.